# Firebase Cloud Functions Deploy Error - Quota Exceeded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy firebase cloud functions, but I'm getting the following:

functions: got "Quota Exceeded" error while trying to update projects/...

and another error:

functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at [URL].

Which quota is being exceeded? And how do I increase that quota?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56847774/13130697) ?

Answer (score 2):

As per [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions) try to delete all your functions and re upload them again.
I do not like this solution as it not something you want to do in a production environment, but it's the only way I found to upload changes.
Besides, I only encounter this issue in my dev project where I upload frequently several times a day on a busy day.

Comment: This worked for me, but I can't see anywhere in that linked doc where it says to delete them all and re upload again. The closest thing I found is where it says to deploy in chunks of 10 to avoid the error. But it doesn't say anything about deleting them all and re uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me , but handled by deploying target functions by firebase deploy --only functions:orgWalletTransCreate