# How to copy asset files before deploying cloud functions to Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase project where I write typescript functions to be deployed into Google Node Cloud functions.
When I run the `firebase deploy --only functions` command, it transpiles my code into javascript and put the js output into a folder called `lib` next to `src` folder where my typescript functions are.
However, some of my functions need access to local files such as .ttf files or some other file types. Those don't get copied over to the lib folder and therefore, I get errors in runtime `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open path/to/file`

Question 1 : How do I get the deploy command to copy assets files to the output folder ?

Question 2 : Given that all my functions live in separate files, in separate folders, and so do my assets, how should I reference my assets so that they can be found ? Should I give the path to the asset file relative to the `lib` folder or relative to where the function lives ?

EDIT -1

See the project structure here :
the code that need the font lives in the some-function.ts file. And it uses the pdfmake library that needs fonts to work.
Here is how I do it in the some-function.ts file :

```
const fonts: TFontDictionary = {
    Poppins: {
      normal: './fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf',
      bold: './fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf',
      italics: './fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf',
      bolditalics: './fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Thin.ttf',
    }
  };
const pdfmake = require('pdfmake');
const printer = new pdfmake(fonts);
```

So how do I reference such fonts given that they are located in the fonts folder. or event if I put them in a separate folder at the root or src ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your directory structure? You can perhaps create a single directory for such files and use a `postbuild` command to copy those over. Then, please also share the code where you specify paths to those files. `path` package makes it easy to deal with relative paths.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited my question to include an example of how the project is structured

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I came to a solution that I would like to share here.

1- First thing, as suggested by @Dharmaraj, I added a script that removes the lib folder, before building the project, and copy my assets files before deploying.
So in the package.json under functions folder, I updated the build command as follow

```
"remove-lib":"rm -rf lib",
"copy-assets":"cp -rf src/path/to/your-folder/fonts lib/path/to/your-folder",
"do-build":"tsc",
"build": "npm run remove-lib && npm run do-build && npm run copy-assets",
```

Actually, adding the remove lib command solved another issue I had with deploying functions. I think this should be the default behaviour because when you rename function files, old ones stick in lib folder causing all sort of issues.

Anyway, now in order to correctly reference your asset, just construct the path as `${__dirname}/fonts/some-font.ttf`  provided that the fonts folder lives in the same folder as the file your are editing.

Comment: Thanks [@Mehdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575754/mehdi) for the solution, I already started with firebase functions with typescript and I was having the same problem like you. Thanks so much for share your solution.